# 2D Array in Swift Playground

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-playground

I'm trying to code a level generator for my game so I'm testing it out in a Swift playground. My level is stored in a 2D Swift array. Everything is great except that I can't see the array data in a useful way. Because it is level data in a tile game, I would like to see the rows and columns arranged neatly. However, the array is currently just a single line resizing to size of the console. How can I see the rows and columns lined up nicely?
Here is my current output:

```
[[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", " ", "&", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", " ", "&", " ", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]
```

I can get a somewhat decent result by resizing the console but there has to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to represent your 2D array with its contents *aligned* in the console, my suggestion is to make the class which holds the array conform to the protocol `CustomStringConvertible`.

For that you have to create a `description` computed property, it's where we do the formatting: we transform the inner arrays into strings and join them with a line separator.

The conformance to the protocol makes the object output the result of the computed property when it's printed.

Example:

```
class BigArrayRepresenter: CustomStringConvertible {

    var bigArray: [[String]] = []

    init(bigArray: [[String]]) {
        self.bigArray = bigArray
    }

    var description: String {
        return bigArray.map { String($0) }.joinWithSeparator("\n")
    }

}
```

Using your array:

```
let source = [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", " ", "&", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", " ", "&", " ", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "&", "&", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]
let representer = BigArrayRepresenter(bigArray: source)
print(representer)
```

We get this result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can put as many line breaks in a 2d array as you would like in order to make the data look nice:

```
let array = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9] 
]
```

Comment: I'm adding to the array programmatically so I can't use that method

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** Write your own `UIView` subclass, and display it using the [`XCPlaygroundLiveViewable` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/XCPlaygroundModuleRef/XCPlayground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016564-CH1-SW12).